How to calculate number of days between dates?
I have the date array dateGas = ["09/28/2013", "10/10/2013"];
I want to calculate the number of full days between the two dates.
Using this:
d1 = datetime(dateGas(1), "InputFormat", "mm/dd/yyyy")
d2 = datetime(dateGas(2), "InputFormat", "mm/dd/yyyy")
delta = days(d2-d1)

will result in delta = 17.999306 which is obviously wrong.
What do I miss here?
Thanks!

The format mm is for minutes, MM is for month.  Your datetime will have the same month, and the difference between the 28th and the 10th is 18 days.

stupid me, thanks a lot!
